# employ log in hours script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

so im Writing python script test i got from scholl but for some reason it dosen't even starts ... no error no nothing ..
its supposed to be and employes log system .. used threading for the infinite loop that's supposed to count the min and creat checking clock for the "employs" and run in background and another function that suppused to read the employ name check if his allready signed in or not and if not to add him to a file with the clock time and name or for the other way around , to log him off  but for some reason the code dosent even run , no error , nothing just blank run screen, ill be glad to get some help ..

```
#!/bin/usr/python
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import time
users=open("logfile.txt","w")
def background():
    seconde = 0
    minute = 0
    hour = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        seconde = seconde + 1
        if seconde == 60:
            minute = minute + 1
            seconde = 0
        elif minute == 60:
                hour = hour + 1
                minute = 0
        alltime = str(hour) + ":" + str(minute) + ":" + str(seconde)
def foreground():
    alin = []
    name = input("Hello Deal employ , please insert your name:\n")
    if name not in alin:
        login=input("your not logged in , do you wish to log?\n")
        if login == "yes" or "Y" or "y" or "Yes":
            users.write("{} Entry Hour :".format(name) + alltime)
            alin.append(name)
        elif login == "no" or "N" or "n" or "No":
                print("ok") and exit()
    elif name in alin:
        logout=input("Your allready signed in , do you wish to check out?\n")
        if logout == "Yes" or "Y" or "Y" or "yes":
            users.write("{} Leaving Hour :".format(name) + alltime)
        elif logout == "no" or "N" or "n" or "No":
            print("ok") and exit()


b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background())
a = threading.Thread(name='foreground', target=foreground())

b.start()
a.start()
```

Comment: You are starting your threads, but are not waiting for them to finish - your "main" code simply quits and kills both threads

Comment: @UnholySheep first thank you for the fast replay ! so what sholdi do ? just wait?

Answer (score 0):

```
b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background())
```

`target` should be a callable object. As is, you are running `background` before starting the thread. As `background` never stops, your program runs forever. Try:

```
b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I'm pretty sure it's not going to work.